# How to use enable_if to enable member functions based on template parameter of class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

In code:

```
template<class T>
struct is_builtin
{
    enum {value = 0};
};

template<>
struct is_builtin<char>
{
    enum {value = 1};
};

template<>
struct is_builtin<int>
{
    enum {value = 1};
};

template<>
struct is_builtin<double>
{
    enum {value = 1};
};

template<class T>
struct My
{
    typename enable_if<is_builtin<T>::value,void>::type f(T arg)
    {
        std::cout << "Built-in as a param.\n";
    }


    typename enable_if<!is_builtin<T>::value,void>::type f(T arg)
    {
        std::cout << "Non - built-in as a param.\n";
    }
};

struct A
{
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    My<int> m;
    My<A> ma;
    m.f(1);
    ma.f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::enable_if<_Test,_Type>'
```

Obviously I don't understand how to use `enable_if`. What I was thinking was that I can enable one or the second one member function from a set of member functions during compilation time but it does not work. Could anyone please explain to me how to do it correctly?
**Edited**
What I really can't understand is why isn't there `typedef` in one of those def. Compiler cannot find it and it wont compile it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use class template parameters to get SFINAE for member functions.

You either need to

- make the member function a member function template instead and use `enable_if` on the member function template's template parameters or
- move the member function `f` into a policy class and specialize the class template using `enable_if`.

Comment: could you provide some example please?

Comment: @There: There is an example of using the second approach (specializing a class template) in [the Boost `enable_if` documentation](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) (see section 3.1).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it works (note that for convenience I replaced your `is_builtin` trait with `std::is_arithmetic` and used further C++11 stuff, but it works any way):

```
template<class T>
struct My
{
    template<typename T_ = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T_>::value>* = nullptr>
    void f(T_ arg)
    {
        std::cout << "Built-in as a param.\n";
    }

    template<typename T_ = T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T_>::value>* = nullptr>
    void f(T_ arg)
    {
        std::cout << "Non - built-in as a param.\n";
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dfb1fb7c5e78e02)

The crucial part is to bring the template parameter into the *immediate context* by using a default function template parameter `T_` which equals the class template parameter `T`. For more details, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855339/c-why-does-sfinae-fail-with-only-a-class-template-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your code by using modified enable_if

```cpp
template < typename T >
struct __Conflict {};

template <bool B, class T = void>
struct __enable_if { typedef __Conflict<T> type; };

template <class T>
struct __enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Example of usage:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Lazy
{
public:
    void _ctor(bool b);
    void _ctor(typename __enable_if<!std::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type);
};

template <typename T>
void Lazy<T>::_ctor(bool b)
{
    std::cout << "bool " << b << std::endl;
};

template <typename T>
void Lazy<T>::_ctor(typename __enable_if<!std::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type t)
{
    std::cout << "T " << t << std::endl;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Lazy<int> i;
    i._ctor(10);
    i._ctor(true);

    Lazy<bool> b;
    b._ctor(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, though I usually try to avoid starting names with underscores because there are rules where any name starting with one or two underscores are reserved in some cases.  Also, is there a reason you named a function `_ctor` instead of just defining a constructor?

Comment: as I remember underscores are used to show the local implementation of something, _ctor is just name of method in my code which I didn't bother to rename

Comment: From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword): 
_Also, **all identifiers that contain a double underscore __ in any position** and each identifier that begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is always reserved and all identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved for use as names in the global namespace. See identifiers for more details._
 So at the very least your `__enable_if` template should be renamed to make sure it never interferes with any standard library implementation details.

Comment: or you can define it in namespace

Answer (score -3):

enable_if expects a metafunction.  To use a bool you need enable_if_c.  I'm surprised you're not getting errors explaining THAT problem.

You can fix your metafunction by declaring a 'type' typedef inside that is simply itself.  Then you can use `boost::enable_if<is_builtin<T>>::type`